# Printing an HTML page with unique number

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am having a php page in which i have captured different values from the previous page, There is also a print button, Which prints all these fields including the unique number. When user clicks on the print button record will be inserted in database and print window displays on the screen. But the problem is there is a unique number on html page, For example if two persons are login at the same time, The will get same unique number, and both will be able to print the same page having same unique number.

How i can control this issue, I also tried to redirect the user to the previous page but its not working.

Here is my php page, Which i am calling using ajax

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','','') or die ("");
mysql_select_db("") or die ("Database Problem");
$query = "select * from print where a = $a;
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO print () VALUES () 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die();
    if(mysql_affected_rows()<>1)
    {
        header ("Location:mainpage.php?uniquenumber=xy");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a unique ID in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181159/generating-a-unique-id-in-php)

Comment: Did you tried `mysql_insert_id`, and remember `mysql_*` is deprecated use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use unisid http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php
To generate an unique id

Comment: Here unique number does not mean auto generated its a database auto increment value. I dont need to generate a unique id

Answer (score 0):

What is this uniquenumber needed for in the client side? I mean having it accessible and editable for the users is kinda dangerous if it's an important value.

If you just need this number to tell apart the different entries in the print table, why not just use and auto_increment index for this table?

Another solution would be session variables. When a user succesfully logs in generate this unique ID based on multiple variables (username, time, browser), that will ensure there won't be repeated values for this ID. Then store the variable like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['ID']=$unique_ID;
```

You can then read it in any other PHP script like this:

```
session_start();
$unique_ID=$_SESSION['ID'];
```

Comment: Let me make it more clear, Actually this unique number is Form Number, user selects a value from the drop down menu and jumps to this printable page, Here form number checks the highest value in the table and add 1 to it, and when user prints it the record is inserted.

Comment: that's exactly what a auto-increment index on a table does :o, I mean, why have it on client side when it's something only the server should know?

Comment: its necessary to display the form number.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the unique number before inserting to database ( Before Printing also ). If the unique no is exist, throw a error message "unique no is already used " and give another unique number ( By loading the HTML Page again or doing something else  ).

Comment: if you check my code i am trying to do the same but its not working